# .on('change', '.class') selects the wrong item (first one only)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several file upload/camera inputs on my site, they all do the same but send different attributes with them:

```
<!--- INPUT 1 --- (MODULE 111111) -->
<input type="file" capture="camera" class="uploadImage"
   data-schedule="1"
   data-schedule-object="27"
   data-schedule-object-module="111111"                
   id="cameraInput_1" 
   name="cameraInput_1">

<!--- INPUT 2 --- (MODULE 222222) -->
<input type="file" capture="camera" class="uploadImage"
   data-schedule="1"
   data-schedule-object="27"
   data-schedule-object-module="222222"                
   id="cameraInput_2" 
   name="cameraInput_2">
```

Now upon click it uploads an image and makes several entries to the DB

**JS Code**

```
$(document).on('change', '.uploadImage', function () {
    var $inpt = $(this);
    var $som = $inpt.attr('data-schedule-object-module');
    ....
    console.log($som);
    ....
});
```

Now, when I click Input 1, everything is fine, but when I choose Input 2 (or any other following), `console.log($som)` always gives me `11111` the attribute from the FIRST. Where am I wrong in my JS?

*Side Note*

Another approach would be to have ONE fileupload and trigger that upon click on a selector that has all the needed attributes, but that would mean some recoding, I think the way I have it currently must be possible somehow?

Comment: That code works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jn1bhc30/

Comment: Works for me in Chrome... https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/vwda09L6/

Comment: have you tried      $(document).on('change', '.uploadImage', function (event) {   console.log(event)}  ?

Comment: Can't understand the downvote, thanks for that. Nevertheless, I figured the issue, the generation of `cameraInput_X` kept repeating after 4 times, so simplyfying the code made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function () {
    var $inpt = $(this);
    var $som = $inpt.attr('data-schedule-object-module');
    console.log($som);
});
```

See **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwub2r9d/)**